# SnakeYAML: How to set bean property type for loading

Tags: java, yaml, javabeans, snakeyaml

Using SnakeYAML's `TypeDescription`, I can add type information about Lists and Maps using:

```
TypeDescription td = new TypeDescription(MyBean.class, "!mybean");
td.putMapPropertyType("mymap", String.class, MyOtherBean.class);
td.putListPropertyType("mylist", MyOtherBean.class);
```

This way, I can populate Collections with instances of MyOtherBean without having to rely on any other tags:

```
---
!mybean
mymap:
  foobar: # will map to an instance of MyOtherBean
    otherbeanprop1: foo
    otherbeanprop2: bar
mylist: # will contain instances of MyOtherBean
  - otherbeanprop1: foo
    otherbeanprop2: bar
```

Is there any easy way to do something like this:

```
td.putPropertyType("myotherbean", MyOtherBean.class);
```

so that the property `myotherbean` in `MyBean` would be populated with a single instance of `MyOtherBean`? Things I am trying to avoid:

- putting additional tags (like `!myotherbean`) in the yaml file
- loading the other beans properties from a Map and constructing the bean myself

I have already played around with this and I think I need to create a custom constructor like this (adapted from the SnakeYAML Documentation):

```
class SelectiveConstructor extends Constructor {
    public SelectiveConstructor() {
        // define a custom way to create a mapping node
        yamlClassConstructors.put(NodeId.mapping, new ConstructMapping() {
            @Override
            protected Object constructJavaBean2ndStep(MappingNode node, Object object) {
                Class type = node.getType();
                if (type.equals(MyBean.class)) {
                    // something
                    if (propertyname.equals("myotherbean")) {
                        // something
                    }
                } else {
                    // redirect creation to Constructor
                    return super.constructJavaBean2ndStep(node, object);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't really understand what exactly is going on there.
Please let me know if there is an easier way. And if there isn't, I would appreciate it if you shared your experience with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is an elegant way to do this.**
If you don't want to do some special tricks with the YAML content, you can use the following two methods of snakeYaml to dump and load yaml content:

```
public String dumpAsMap(Object data)              // dump method
public <T> T loadAs(Reader io, Class<T> type)     // load method
```

In your scenario,

dump :

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
// init bean...
String yamlContent = yaml.dumpAsMap(bean);
```

load :

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
MyBean bean = yaml.loadAs(reader, MyBean.class);
```

Of course, you should implement the getter and setter of your classes. For details, you can take a look at the [example](https://github.com/sel-fish/SnakeYamlExample/blob/master/src/main/java/SnakeYamlExample.java) here.